# Use Express JS .all() method: detect which VERB was actually used

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request, express

I'm going to create an `/api` endpoint blindly proxying requests and responses back and forth to the legacy RESTful API system (written in Ruby and hosted on a different domain).

This an intermediary transitional step, so that should just work.

So, I see how that can be easily achieved with `app.all()`. But as the API is RESTful I do also have to maintain the HTTP verb used for the request - so, can I detect it from the `req` object? If not, of course I can subscribe 5 handlers for GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, but it will be much better to avoid this.

Also, how should I deal with the request body (query string and payload)?
I assume I'll need to manually recreate the query string from the parsed `req.query` and pass `req.body` to `request` https://github.com/mikeal/request as is - is it right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I guess you all need is `req.method`. And to deal with body, add `express.bodyParser()` middleware.

Comment: any suggestion on what to do with GET and POST params?

Comment: GET params is req.query. Post params is req.body (if parsed with middleware). Have you checked expressjs guide?

Comment: I have the bodyParser, but my concerns are (see in the ticket): 1) should I _recreate the query string from the parsed query and add it to the URL_, and 2) should I pass the _parsed_ body to `request`?

Comment: Well, probably express is not best solution for you in that case, why not just use nodejs http.createServer and get all plain data in req object?

Comment: because this project is not for API only (otherwise why having such a plain proxy at all?:)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to pass requests and return the response then you are looking for a **proxy**.

I'd recommend checking out [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). Just load the proxy library, init a proxy, and proxy all requests.

Comment: Looks promising. But there are nuances. The remote end has a different structure (`nodeapp.com/api/v1/something?get=var` relates to `api.rubyapp.com/v1/something?get=var`). It is also not completely clear to me what will happen with the query string (especially if I have a mixture of GET and POST params)